# Manual bibliography format does not exists?

Tags: bibliographies

In the [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Standard_templates) for LaTeX bibliography compilations, the following is listed as a standard template:

```
@manual 
    Technical manual

        Required fields: title.
        Optional fields: author, organization, address, edition, month, year, note.
```

However,

```
@manual{bioc2201man,
title="{Principles of Molecular Biology (Advanced) Course Syllabus and Laboratory Manual, Session 2, 2011}",
organization="{School of Biotechnology and Biomolecular Sciences}",
year="2011"
}
```

will not compile.

However assigning the same as an "article" will.

Is the wiki wrong or have I missed something?

Here is a minimal example, as requested:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

The method was derived from {\it Principles of Molecular Biology (Advanced) Course Syllabus and Laboratory Manual, Session 2, 2011}~\cite{bioc2201man}.  Variations to be noted are...

\subsection*{References}

\bibliography{bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{natbib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The wiki isn't wrong.  You need to give a minimal example that shows what you are doing.  Using `natbib` and e.g. either the `plainnat` or `alpha` bibliography styles, this entry works (although since there is no author, the `\cite` command yields "Sch [2011]"). Perhaps the bibliography style you are using doesn't support the `@manual` entry.

Comment: @Alan Munn - minimal example attached to OP.  See what you think.

Comment: @ptrcao: `natibib` is not a bibliography style, it's a LaTeX package. Either use a style such as `unsrt` without loading `natibib` or `\usepackage{natbib}` and use a `natbib` style such as `unsrtnat`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Joseph is right.  I appear to have misunderstood.  Also, the other half of the solution is for whatever reason I don't understand, you have to delete the Aux files.  That seems to reset the typesetting system and clears up errors.  Is that consistent with what you guys know?

Comment: @ptrcao: Often deleting the `.aux` file is needed when there is an error leading to the 'wrong' data being written. Unless thee is an objection, I'll close this question as 'too localized' in a bit.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I see, not a problem.  Feel free to close it, I have my answer and that is what counts :)  Thanks again, no doubt we will speak again